# What is the probability that a random 6-digit number will have at least one 0, at least one 1, and at least one 2?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Hi this a question from my textbook: A first course in probability, It doesn't have the solution so I'm curious as to what the answer is. This is the question:

What is the probability that a random 6-digit number will have at least one 0, at
least one 1, and at least one 2? (the number can't start with a 0).

$My Answer$

Well is know that all the possible combinations of a 6 - digit number that doesn't start with $0$ is: $9(10^5)$

Next I considered the all the possible combinations of a $6$ - digit number not having at least one 0, at least one 1, and at least one 2 which is $7^6$

so: $1 - 7^6/9(10^5) = 0.87 $

is this correct?

Comment: First of all, do you assume equiprobability of 6-digit numbers?

Comment: No IMHO this is wrong. Number containing $0$ but not containing $1$ is also should be excluded so the number is of all numbers not satisfying the conditions is higher than $7^6$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The probability that a number has at least one $1$, at least one $2$, and at least one $0$ is $1$ minus the probability of having no $0$'s, **or** no $1$'s, **or** no $2$'s. So, label $A$ as the event "no zeros", $B$ as the event "no ones", $C$ as the event "no twos".
You want:
$$
1-P(A\cup B\cup C) =1-\left(P(A) + P(B) + P(C)\right) +\left(P(A\cap B) + P(A\cap C) + P(B\cap C)\right) - P(A\cap B \cap C) = 1-\frac{ 9^6+2\cdot 8\cdot 9^5 }{9\cdot 10^5}+\frac{2\cdot 8^6+7\cdot 8^5}{9\cdot 10^5} -\frac{7^6}{9\cdot 10^5}= \frac{1993}{30000}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

event A - number has at least one 0;
event B - number has at least one 1;
event C - number has at least one 2;

A and B and C = not[ (not A) or (not B) or (not C) ]

Prob[ (not A) or (not B) or (not C) ] = Prob(not A) + Prob(not B)+ Prob(not C) - Prob[(not A) and (not B)] - Prob[(not A) and (not C)] - Prob[(not C) and (not B)] + Prob[(not A) and (not B) and (not C)]

Comment: He is doing inclusion exclusion, it's a good strategy for this problem. Draw a venn diagram for the events and you'll see what he's talking about.